# Transaction Not getting rolled back in spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-JPA to roll back Transaction when a RuntimeException occurs in my class.

**Controller.java**

```
@Controller
public class ParticipantController {
    private ParticipantService participantService;

    public ParticipantController(ParticipantService participantService) { this.participantService = participantService; }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<ParticipantRequest> addParticipant() {
        System.out.println ("Controller New " + Thread.currentThread ().getName ());
        return (participantRequest) -> {
            try {
                participantService.save (participantRequest);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace ();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**ParticipantService.java**

```
@Service
public class ParticipantService {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    public void save (ParticipantRequest participantRequest) {
        ParticipantCreatedEvent participantCreatedEvent = new ParticipantCreatedEvent
                (participantRequest.getEventId (), participantRequest.getTeamId (),
                participantRequest.getFirstName (), participantRequest.getLastName (),
                participantRequest.getEmail (), participantRequest.getContactNumber (),
                participantRequest.getOrganization (),
                participantJpaRepository.findMaxDisplayOrder (participantRequest.getEventId ()) + 1);
        participant.setEventId (participantRequest.getEventId ());
        participant.save(createParticipantCommand, participantCreatedEvent);
        throw new RuntimeException ();
        // throw new EntityDoesNotExistsException ("Error", new Exception ("Hello"));
    }
}
```

The transaction is not getting rolled back. Can anyone please help what am I doing wrong?

The entire code is uploaded here -> https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/app-services

Comment: per the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) RuntimeExceptions are always rollbacked. What makes you believe that your transaction was not rollbacked?

Comment: @tremendous7 - I know the transaction should be rolled back as per the doc. But i could see the participant data being persisted into my DB,